# greater z-index within lower z-index?

Tags: css

I cannot seem to figure out a way to assign greater `z-index` priority to an element that has a parent with a lower `z-index` than an overlay element.

Consider this example:

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: #F00; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;">
    <div style="width: 50px; height: 100px; background: #00F; position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 0; z-index: 3;"></div>
</div>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; background: #0F0; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 50px; z-index: 2;"></div>
```

The result:

[image]

The expected result:

[image]

Comment: The result is the expected result. As far as I know, the z-index is relative to the parent, once you give it a `position`, not to the document.

Comment: You can use "position: absolute; z-index: auto" for the first div.

Comment: @infous Not a solution, since `z-index` for that element is important. Just had to move the element outside.

Comment: About @LeeR comment, I found a demo in the following link. You can see that the z-index refers to the stacking context. https://web.dev/learn/css/z-index/#stacking-context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this, *but* only if the parent doesn't have a `position: relative` or `absolute` property on it. So if you remove the `position: absolute` from the first div, it'll work as expected.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GEnHC/

Comment: This works as long as you're not doing anything else on the element that creates a stacking context (like a transform)

Answer (score 1):

Elements get ordered on each level *first*. So it orders your red and green box, then it orders your blue box *inside* the red box, which has already been determined to be behind the green box. There is no way around this. You'd have to consider an alternate layout of your elements which would allow the layout you desire, such as simply [removing the blue box from its parent](http://jsfiddle.net/TBWfZ/1/).